# SWIG unsigned char and byte[]

Tags: swig, binary-data

I've looked all over the place.  I have tried some of the techniques on this site.  To no avail.

I have a c++ global function

```
char* squid( char* buff, int len );
```

I create a .i file

```
%module Crabby

%include "arrays_java.i"

%{
/* headers here are included in the wrapper code */
#include "sponge.h"
%}



%typemap(jtype) (const signed char *arr, size_t sz) "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) (const signed char *arr, size_t sz) "byte[]"
%typemap(jni) (const signed char *arr, size_t sz) "jbyteArray"
%typemap(javain) (const signed char *arr, size_t sz) "$javainput"

%typemap(in) (const signed char* arr, size_t sz) {
  $1 = JCALL2(GetByteArrayElements, jenv, $input, NULL);
  const size_t sz = JCALL1(GetArrayLength, jenv, $input);
  $2 = $1 + sz;
}

%typemap(freearg) (const signed char *arr, size_t sz) {
  // Or use  0 instead of ABORT to keep changes if it was a copy
  JCALL3(ReleaseByteArrayElements, jenv, $input, $1, JNI_ABORT); 
}

%apply (const signed char* arr, size_t sz) { (const unsigned char* buff, int len) }
%apply (const signed char* arr, size_t sz) { (const unsigned char* query, int queryLen) }

%include "sponge.h"
```

No matter what I do the interface is always

```
public static String Squid(String buff, int len)
```

if I remove the unsigned I get illegal conversions in the cxx wrapper

this is Swig 2.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Your interface is close, but has the following issues:

1. `const` matters for `%apply`
2. You need to exactly match the signed/unsigned qualifier for `buff` (there is no qualifier in the declaration you showed.
3. Your in typemap needs `numinputs=1` to compress it to just one Java input.
4. Setting the size to be a computed pointer doesn't make much sense.

So the fixed interface looks like:

```
%module Crabby

%include "arrays_java.i"

%{
/* headers here are included in the wrapper code */
#include "sponge.h"
%}

%typemap(jtype) (const signed char *arr, size_t sz) "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) (const signed char *arr, size_t sz) "byte[]"
%typemap(jni) (const signed char *arr, size_t sz) "jbyteArray"
%typemap(javain) (const signed char *arr, size_t sz) "$javainput"

%typemap(in,numinputs=1) (const signed char* arr, size_t sz) {
  $1 = JCALL2(GetByteArrayElements, jenv, $input, NULL);
  const size_t sz = JCALL1(GetArrayLength, jenv, $input);
  $2 = sz;
}

%typemap(freearg) (const signed char *arr, size_t sz) {
  // Or use  0 instead of ABORT to keep changes if it was a copy
  JCALL3(ReleaseByteArrayElements, jenv, $input, $1, JNI_ABORT);
}

%apply (const signed char* arr, size_t sz) { ( char* buff, int len) }

%include "sponge.h"
```

Comment: Is there a way to fix the function signature so that it only takes a string?

Comment: @soandos yes, but the question then is how you want to map the string on to `char*`, as `jchar` isn't the same as a char. Do you want the number of bytes as the length, or the number of characters?